# Group JS events

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I currently have four `change()` events that fire exactly the same code (see below), so I'm wondering if there is a way of grouping these events in one line to save reapeating code four times?

Thanks.

```
/** Check for a change to any of the search dropdowns */
$('#job-roles').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
$('#ind-services').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
$('#bus-services').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
$('#indi-services').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
```

Comment: `letter = $_GET('staff_search');`???

Comment: +1 @Matt hahaha I didn't spot that !!!!

Comment: @Matt - What's the problem with that code?

Comment: @DavidGard: If thats supposed to be a variable, you should prefix the statement with `var`. What is `$_GET['staff_search']`? You mean `"<?php echo addcslashes($_GET['staff_search'], '"'); ?>"` (PHP is rusty.. but hope you get the gist).

Comment: @Matt - Yes, I should have `var` before the statement. `$_GET` is a function. I add the letter that is being searched for to the end of the url (i.e. `#?staff_search=m`) and then use this to get the letter. I need to have the letter in the URI as each time a user changes a search criteria the search is automatically run. This is the best way I could think to do it, and `$_GET()` is just comfortable because I use PHP.

Comment: @DavidGard: Ahhha, `$_GET` is your own JavaScript function? +1 for confusing the **hell** out of me!

Comment: @Matt - Ha ha, yep - something I wrote a long time ago when I was really not that familier with JS, as it's just stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#job-roles, #indi-services, #ind-services, #bus-services').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
```

Comment: Perfect - I'd tried wrapping them all individually in quotes, but not as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**: give them all the same class and attach the event to all of them `$('.someClass').change(...)`

**Option 2**: Group the event: `$('#job-roles, #ind-services, ... ').change(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Use a class ?

Give all the elements a class of say `doSomething` then use the following code to implement the listener:

```
$('.doSomething').change(function(e){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
});
```

Comment: Would work, but want to avoid fiddeling with this code too much. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, in addition to the excellent ones already described, is simply:

```
(function(){
  function doCoolStuff(){
    letter = $_GET('staff_search');
    initiate_staff_search(letter, '<?php echo $staff_search_nonce; ?>', '<?php echo $name_search_type; ?>')
  }

  $('#job-roles').change(function(e){
    doCoolStuff();
  });
  $('#ind-services').change(function(e){
    doCoolStuff();
  });
  $('#bus-services').change(function(e){
    doCoolStuff();
  });
  $('#indi-services').change(function(e){
    doCoolStuff();
  });
}());
```

Comment: Still quite repetitive, repetitive, repetitive, why would you want that?

Comment: Still quite repetitive, repetitive, repetitive, why would you want that?

Comment: I did consider that route, but my advanced search will eventually have 8-10 dropdowns for various choices, so it would be a bit long winded. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: Agreed it is not as terse as your examples, but there are cases for it. For example, you may not be able to (or want to) add any markup. Also, you may want to do things mostly the same, but have some uniqueness in one case or another. In any event, just adding another option to the list of possibilities.